# Callable Statement Not Found while using ojdbc7.jar

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

While i am running my application with ojdbc14.jar it works fine but when i changed it to ojdbc7.jar

Compiler throws error in callable statement

Comment: Would be helpful if you could provide the piece of code where it is failing. Or at least the correct exception message. Do you mean a `callable statement`? Might be a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while working with odbc14 this problem occurs due to the driver class.
You need to change your import statement from:

```
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement;
```

to this :

```
import oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement;
```

In short delete the word "driver" from your import statement.